# Converting OAuthConfig to OAuth2 for Apps Script for sending Google spreadsheet as attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

the below script for where it collects the data from a google spreadsheet and sends a mail by sending as excel attachment file.

this was due to OAuthConfig class is deprecated. google up and found that there is one alternative for this and tried to include OAuth2 for Apps Script and opted few modification in the existing code. still i feel that the i have missed something else.

can anyone correct me in the code.

```
   function sendEmail() {


  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Abstract");
  var startRow = 4  // First row of data to process
  var numRows  = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)

  var CurrentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var contacts = CurrentSheet.getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var database_sheet = CurrentSheet.getSheetByName("Database");
  var numRows = contacts.getLastRow();

  var emailSubject    = "Status on Approvals Due for Incepted Batches";
  var emailSalutation = "<p>Dear All, </p> <p>Please find the enclosed details pertaining to Status on Approvals Due for Incepted Batches</p>";
  var emailSignature  = "<p>Thanks & Regards </p>";
  var emailYourName   = "Jimson Jose";
  var emailFrom = GmailApp.getAliases()[2];
  var newLine = "<p></p>";
  var emailReplyTo = "jimson.jose@dfgs.org";

  var toContacts1 = contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues();
  var toContacts2 = database_sheet.getRange(2, 35, numRows, 1).getValues();
  var toContacts = (toContacts1.join("")).replace(',','') + "," + toContacts2;
  var ccContacts = contacts.getRange(2, 3, numRows, 1).getValues().join("");

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var message_body2 = new Array();

  var message_body1 = "<html> <body> <p> <table border='2' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2' style='text-align: center;'> <tbody style='font-size:15px;'>" 
  +"<tr> <th rowspan='2' bgcolor = '#B45F06'><font color='White'> Zone </font></th>" 
  +"<th bgcolor = '#b45f06' colspan='3'><font color='white'>No.of Batches</font></th></tr>"
  +"<tr> <th bgcolor = '#B2476B'><font color='White'> Total </font></th>"
  +"<th bgcolor = '#604000'><font color='White'> Due at </br>Zonal Accounts</font></th>"
  +"<th bgcolor = '#1c4587'><font color='White'> Due on </br> Rejection </font></th></tr>"
  +"<tr style='font-size:13px;'> <th bgcolor = '#5B0F00'><font color='White'> " + sheet.getRange('A3').getValues() + " </font></th>"
  +"<th bgcolor = '#5B0F00'><font color='White'> " + sheet.getRange('B3').getValues() + " </font></th>"
  +"<th bgcolor = '#5B0F00'><font color='White'> " + sheet.getRange('C3').getValues() + " </font></th>"
  +"<th bgcolor = '#5B0F00'><font color='White'> " + sheet.getRange('D3').getValues() + " </font></th></tr>";
  var message_body3 =   "</tbody> </table> </p> </body> </html>"; 


  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    var row = data[i];
    var dist_val = row[0];  // timestamp column

    if (dist_val != "" ) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      message_body2[i] = "<tr style='font-size:12px;'>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#FFAD33'><font color='black'>" + row[0] + "</font></td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#E6B8AF'><font color='black'>"+ row[1] + "</font></td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#B5A380'><font color='black'>"+ row[2] + "</font></td>"
      +"<td bgcolor = '#c9daf8'><font color='black'>"+ row[3] + "</font></td></tr>"; 
    }
  }

  var emailBody = message_body1 + message_body2.join("") + message_body3;
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sheetName = "Due for Down Payment Approval Status - Incepted Batches";

  var subject = "Status on Approvals Due for Incepted Batches"; //old settings
  var emailMsg = emailSalutation + " " + newLine + emailBody + emailSignature + emailYourName;

  var token = oauth2Service().getAccessToken(); //this will be setup from step 1

  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");

  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");

// NEW code oAuth.2
  var requestData = { method : 'get',headers : {'oAuthServiceName': 'google'+ token},contentType:'application/json',muteHttpExceptions:true};

  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "oAuthServiceName": "google", "oAuthUseToken": "always"};


  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID;
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  var attach = {fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xlsx"};

 var advancedArgs = {htmlBody:emailMsg, from:emailFrom, cc:ccContacts, name:emailYourName, replyTo:emailReplyTo, attachments:[attach]};
GmailApp.sendEmail(toContacts, emailSubject , emailMsg , advancedArgs);

};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Oauth2 library set up correctly and token has a valid token from this call:

```
 var token = oauth2Service().getAccessToken();
```

then  requestData will look like:

```
var requestData = { method : 'get',headers : {'Authorization':'Bearer '+ token},contentType:'application/json',muteHttpExceptions:true};
```